# azure devops yaml 'if' not evaluating as expected

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

Oh man, I'm having a really time with the yaml learning curve.  Something that seems so simple, I just can't get to work.
I have this nested parameter group (not sure if that's the correct term) -

```
build: {
    configuration: '',
    nugetSource: '',
    dotnetVersion: '',
    projectsToPublish: '',
    releaseCandidate: 'False',
    tag: ''
}
```

I'm trying to then use an 'if' to set a variable for pool, dependent on the parameters.build.dotnetVersion passed in.

```
- job: build
    displayName: Build & test
    variables:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.build.dotnetVersion,6.0.200) }}:
      - name: buildpool
        value: build-dotnet6
    - ${{ if ne(parameters.build.dotnetVersion,6.0.200) }}:
      - name: buildpool
        value: build-default
    pool: $(buildpool)
```

So even though I have confirmed with an echo command that the value of parameters.build.dotnetVersion is 6.0.200, buildpool is always getting set to build-default.

I also tried wrapping 6.0.200 in single quotes, but didn't work as expected.